# error in SQL syntax

Tags: php

the error is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= ''OR author= ''' at line 1

My php code:

```
<?php
include "search.php";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM bookinfo";

if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
$search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['searchbox']);

$sql .= "WHERE title= '{$search_term}'";
$sql .= "OR author= '{$search_term}'";
}

$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

?>
<form name="searchform" method="POST" >
Search:<input type="text" name="searchbox" />
<input type="submit" name="search" value="search book" />
</form>
<table width="70%" cellpadding="5" cellspace="5">
<tr>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td>Author</td>
    <td>Price</td>
</tr>
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
?>   
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['title']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['author']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['price']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php }
?>

</table>
```

Comment: Do: `var_dump($sql)` before you use it and look at the SQL.

Comment: Add a space before WHERE in `" WHERE title= '{$search_term}'";` and before OR in `" OR author= '{$search_term}'";` You are concatenating one large string from 3 parts, you have to think what the end result will be

Comment: echo the query first echo($sql);exit; and copy the query and try to run in your mysql server

Comment: I've no idea in the first place, why you're concatenating those. Concatenating is mostly used for multi queries or is you have any other loop between.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i am new to php coding, so i am not too sure what is "var_dump($sql" 
and "echo the query first echo($sql);exit; and copy the query and try to run in your mysql server"
i am following some youtube video of the code, and the person code works w/o spacing, weird.

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['search'])) { ... normal one line query }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a blank space before `OR` and `WHERE`. Currently it is generating something like -

```
SELECT * FROM bookinfoWHERE title= 'hello'OR author= 'Hello'
```

Should be -

```
$sql .= " WHERE title= '{$search_term}'";
$sql .= " OR author= '{$search_term}'";
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM bookinfoWHERE title= '{$search_term}' ...` I don't think OP has a table called: `bookinfoWHERE`

Comment: omg thanks! cant believe that the space is causing me spending time looking for other errors!

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed space before  OR:

```
$sql .= " WHERE title= '{$search_term}'";
$sql .= " OR author= '{$search_term}'";
```

Comment: You need to add space in WHERE too!!

Comment: @Saty, yeah, thanks for note. Changed.

Answer (score 1):

you need to put `space` before both the append statements:

```
$sql .= " WHERE title= '{$search_term}'";
$sql .= " OR author= '{$search_term}'";
```